# Coupling in Enumerations

Tags: java, enums, decoupling

I've come across some examples of state machines written as enumerations. For instance:

```
public enum State {
    INITIAL {
        @Override
        public State process(char ch) { return MIDDLE; }
    },

    MIDDLE {
        @Override
        public State process(char ch) {
            switch (ch) {
                case 'a': return INITIAL;
                default: return FINAL;
            }
        }
    },

    FINAL {
        @Override
        public State process(char ch) { return FINAL; }
    };

    public abstract State process(char ch);

    public static State initial() { return INITIAL; }
}
```

What concerns me, is having the constants know each other.
Their implementations are subject to change, and if constants are added (or removed) more changes are implied.

However, all changes are contained in the enumeration, unless outside code references the constants directly and makes assumptions about the transition table.

So, is this code highly coupled, loosely coupled, or is it *subjective*?

Comment: Yeah, I could see a separate class the holds the logic for state transitions, instead of encompassing that in the enum.

Comment: @GriffeyDog The enum could be private and nested inside some class that represented a proper instance of the state machine. So, I assume this is the shorthand version of doing things, and is probably not a good practice in any kind of serious code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is too tightly coupled for a flexible tool.

Something looser would be much more flexible:

```
public enum State {
  INITIAL,
  MIDDLE,
  FINAL;
  public static State initial() {
    return INITIAL;
  }

}

// A 'null' for the Character matches anything.
static Map<Pair<State,Character>, State> machine = new HashMap<>();
static {
  // Always transit from INITIAL to MIDDLE
  machine.put(new Pair<State,Character>(State.INITIAL,null), State.MIDDLE);
  // An 'a' transitrs us to FINAL
  machine.put(new Pair<State,Character>(State.MIDDLE,'a'), State.FINAL);
  // Anything else takes us back to INITIAL
  machine.put(new Pair<State,Character>(State.MIDDLE,null), State.FINAL);
  // Stay in FINAL once there.
  machine.put(new Pair<State,Character>(State.FINAL,null), State.FINAL);

}
```

Comment: This is minor, but why did you decide to add the `initial()` factory method?

Comment: @PaulBellora - It was in the original and it seemed a good idea - the initial state of a system need not be defined by the machine, it can be defined by the state-list. On further thought that may have been incorrect but I don't think it was wrong.

Comment: Ah I missed it in the OP's snippet. Understood.